# ERROR ITMS-90057 "Missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString."

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Getting the following error when trying to submit my archive to the App Store:

```
ERROR ITMS-90057 "Missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString."
```

BUT HERE'S THE TWIST — This is a snippet of my plist:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>3.1.4</string>
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over.

Comment: I didn't. Please read carefully— I'm getting errors 90057, 90056, and 90049. They are not the same. They MAY be caused by the same thing. I don't know, because I haven't solved any of them yet.

Comment: Please do as you've been asked. Edit _one_ question that assembles them. "I'm getting various ERROR-ITMS messages when trying to submit to the App Store..." or similar. Anyway I think the question has been answered correctly already: it's a bug at iTunes Connect and you should cool your jets for a while until Apple fixes it. Sure, it's frustrating, but don't take it out on Stack Overflow.