# ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion."

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Getting this error while trying to submit my archive to the App Store

```
ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion."
```

Here is a snippet from my plist:

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>3.1.5</string>
```

Using xCode 7.0.1

Comment: Please delete this question and add it to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271838/error-itms-90057-missing-plist-key-the-info-plist-file-is-missing-the-required).

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over.

Comment: I didn't. Please read carefully— I'm getting errors 90057, 90056, and 90049. They are not the same. The MAY be caused by the same thing. I don't know, because I haven't solved any of them yet.

Comment: did you get the solution?